# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'queryRepository'

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am working on a Spring-Boot application to connect to a database. My problem has to do with failing to autowire and the `JdbcTemplate`. My understanding of autowiring and `JdbcTemplate` is limited, so the error really could be anything. Explaining what is wrong, how to fix it, and how to avoid this/these problem(s) in the future would be greatly appreciated.

I have left out my sql files and `application.properties` because they are not relevant to the autowiring problem.

Addition, if it is not too much trouble, could someone explain the concept of autowiring? I have look at posts on this site of people explaining the concept and I still don't really understand it. I know that autowiring does something automatically. I believe creating a bean and filling it with some sort of information, but that's about it.

Stack Trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'queryRepository': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate edu.ucdavis.QueryRepository.jdbcTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:760) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at edu.ucdavis.QuickControllerApplication.main(QuickControllerApplication.java:20) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate edu.ucdavis.QueryRepository.jdbcTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

**Query.java**

```
**************************************************************
 * Query.java - This object should hold all the information that
 * the person is looking for in their query search.
 **************************************************************/

package edu.ucdavis.objects;

import edu.ucdavis.ProjectConstants;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Date;

/**************************************************************
 * queryIDNumber - a long that holds the individual data of an
 * individual query. Each query will have a unique number
 * associated with it.
 **************************************************************/
public class Query {
    private Long queryID;           //each query must have a unique ID Number which will go in the URL when the user is viewing the result of the query search.
    private static Long totalQueryIDs = 0L;      //holds the value of how many queries have been created over the life of the program
    private static Long largestIDNumber = 1L;    //holds the largest possible ID that the program knows of; used as a check

    public Query()
    {
        this.queryID = generateQueryID();
        updateOutputFile(this.queryID);
    }

    public Query(Long generatedIDNumber){
        this.queryID = generatedIDNumber;
        updateOutputFile(this.queryID);
    }

    /**************************************************************
     * generateQueryID - Generate a ID Number for a query. ID
     * Number must be unique, and then is assigned to queryID
     **************************************************************/
    public Long generateQueryID(){
        Long generatedNumber;

        //Finds the totalQueryIDs stored in QUERY_COUNT_FILE
        generatedNumber = findNumberOfQueries();

        //System.out.println("generatedNumber " + generatedNumber + "\n");

        //generatedNumber is not a legal value, so assigning the default minimum
        if (generatedNumber < ProjectConstants.MIN_ID_NUMBER){
            totalQueryIDs = ProjectConstants.MIN_ID_NUMBER;
        }
        //if the next available number has not been used, increase totalQueryIDs
        else if(largestIDNumber < generatedNumber) {
            largestIDNumber = generatedNumber;
            totalQueryIDs = generatedNumber;
        }

        return queryID = totalQueryIDs;
    }

    public Long getQueryID(){
        return queryID;
    }

    public Long getTotalQueryIDs(){
        return totalQueryIDs;
    }

    public void setTotalQueryIDs(Long number){
        totalQueryIDs = number;
    }

    public void setQueryID(Long number){
        queryID = number;
    }

    public void setLargestIDNumber(Long number){
        largestIDNumber = number;
    }

    /**************************************************************
     * findNumberOfQueries - This function finds out how many
     * queries have been generated so far. This function will check
     * a text file that will contain the past number of queries
     * that have been generated.
     **************************************************************/
    public Long findNumberOfQueries(){
        //Check a file. If queryCountFile.txt is not found then numberOfQueries is considered 0 and becomes 1?
        try {
            //Assume default encoding.
            File file = new File(ProjectConstants.QUERY_COUNT_FILE);
            //FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);

            //Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            try{
                //System.out.println("got here\n");   //debug statement
                String line;    //temp var

                //skip first SKIP_NUM_LINES_IN_FILE lines in QUERY_COUNT_FILE
                for (int count = 0; count < ProjectConstants.SKIP_NUM_LINES_IN_FILE; count++) {
                    line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    //System.out.print(line);         //debug statement
                }

                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                //System.out.println("This is the value of line " + line);        //debug
                while (line != null) {
                    //System.out.println("stuff bufferedReader got: " + line);    //debug
                    totalQueryIDs = Long.parseLong(line);
                    line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                }
            }
            catch(IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error reading to file '" + ProjectConstants.QUERY_COUNT_FILE + "'");
            }

            //Close the file.
            bufferedReader.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error writing to file '" + ProjectConstants.QUERY_COUNT_FILE + "'");
        }

        return totalQueryIDs;
    }

    /**************************************************************
     * updateOutputFile - This function will update QUERY_COUNT_FILE
     * with the new totalQueryIDs as a result of recently creating
     * a Query object.
     **************************************************************/
    public void updateOutputFile(Long IDNumber) {
        try {
            Date date = new Date();

            //Assume default encoding.
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(ProjectConstants.QUERY_COUNT_FILE);

            //Always wrap FileWriter in BufferedWriter.
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

            bufferedWriter.write("FILE LAST WRITTEN TO ON: " + date + "\n");
            bufferedWriter.write("totalQueryIDs:\n");
            //Need to check the value of the incoming ID against holderOfUniqueIDs that holds all other IDs (the size) to make sure that the new query isn't overriding totalQueryIDs
            //MAYBE do it like this...
            if (largestIDNumber < IDNumber){
                bufferedWriter.write(Long.toString(IDNumber));
                largestIDNumber = IDNumber;
                totalQueryIDs = IDNumber;
            }else {
                bufferedWriter.write(Long.toString(largestIDNumber));
            }

            //Close the file.
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error writing to file '" + ProjectConstants.QUERY_COUNT_FILE + "'");
        }
    }
}
```

**ProjectConstants.java**

```
/**************************************************************
 * This file holds the constants used throughout the program
 **************************************************************/

package edu.ucdavis;

public class ProjectConstants {


    public static final Long MIN_ID_NUMBER = 1L;  //minimum ID Number that can be ever generated by the program
    public static final String QUERY_COUNT_FILE = "queryCountFile.txt";       //this file will simply hold a number that states how many queries have been created
    public static final int SKIP_NUM_LINES_IN_FILE = 2;   //the first X number of lines that will skipped in QUERY_COUNT_FILE
    //public static final Long MAX_ID_NUMBER = 9223372036854775807L; //maximum ID Number that can be ever generated by the program
}
```

**QuickControllerApplication.java**

```
/**************************************************************
 * This Spring Boot project should make a controller that can
 * quickly search a database.
 **************************************************************/

package edu.ucdavis;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
public class QuickControllerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        QuickController quickController = new QuickController();
        quickController.populateOutputFile(ProjectConstants.QUERY_COUNT_FILE);
        SpringApplication.run(QuickControllerApplication.class, args);
        //everthing below this line is for testing purposes
        //Query littleQuery = new Query(3L);

        //littleQuery.testPrint();
        //System.out.println("Num of findNumberOfQueries() " + littleQuery.findNumberOfQueries());
    }
}
```

**QuickControllerApplicationTests.java**

```
package edu.ucdavis;

import edu.ucdavis.objects.Query;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import java.util.List;

import org.junit.*;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(QuickControllerApplication.class)
public class QuickControllerApplicationTests {
    @Autowired
    private QueryRepository queryRepository;

    @org.junit.Test
    public void findAllUsers() {
        List<Query> queries = queryRepository.findAll();
        Assert.assertNotNull(queries);
        Assert.assertTrue(!queries.isEmpty());
    }

    @Test
    public void findQueryById() {
        Query query = queryRepository.findQueryById(1L);
        Assert.assertNotNull(query);
    }

    /*@Test
    public void createUser() {
        Query query = new Query(1L);
        Query savedUser = queryRepository.create(query);
        Query newUser = queryRepository.findUserById(savedUser.getQueryID());
        Assert.assertNotNull(newUser);
        Assert.assertEquals("John", newUser.getName());
        Assert.assertEquals("john@gmail.com", newUser.getEmail());
    }
    */
}
```

**QueryRepository.java**

```
package edu.ucdavis;

import edu.ucdavis.objects.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreator;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.GeneratedKeyHolder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.KeyHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
public class QueryRepository {
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Transactional
    public List<Query> findAll(){
        return jdbcTemplate.query("select * from queries", new QueryRowMapper());

    }
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Query findQueryById(Long id){
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select * from queries where id=?", new Object[]{id}, new QueryRowMapper());
    }

    /*public Query create(final Query query){
        final String sql = "insert into queries(queryID,totalQueryIDs) values(?,?)";

        KeyHolder holder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
        jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
            @Override
            public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                ps.setLong(1, query.getQueryID());
                ps.setLong(2, query.getTotalQueryIDs());
                return ps;
            }
        }, holder);

        int newUserId = holder.getKey().intValue();
        query.setQueryID(Integer.toUnsignedLong(newUserId) );
        return query;
    }
    */
}

class QueryRowMapper implements RowMapper<Query> {
    @Override
    public Query mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        Query query = new Query();
        query.setQueryID(rs.getLong("queryID"));
        query.setTotalQueryIDs(rs.getLong("totalQueryIDs"));
        query.setLargestIDNumber(rs.getLong("largestIDNumber"));
        return query;
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>edu.ucdavis</groupId>
    <artifactId>QuickController</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>QuickController</name>
    <description>This Spring Boot project should make a controller that can quickly search a database. This project was created by Michael Layman.</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: You are not able to create the bean queryRepository because the depedency bean JdbcTemplate does not exist. You have make sure that the bean exists. How did you configure you beans? You should include the JdbcTemplate in your config

Comment: I am not understanding what you mean. I have provided all my code with the exception of two .sql files and `application.properties`. Based on what you are saying, it seems like I have missed writing some important code (maybe even a whole file) when dealing with JdbcTemplate.

Comment: If you are going to provide that many files it is better to throw them into a GitHub repo so that people can fork / clone it and provide you with potential pull requests so you can see what they did to resolve the issue. What you are asking about autowiring is at the core of the Spring Framework and will be hard for someone to provide a decent overview in a comment or answer. I am on my phone but when I get to a computer there are some good docs and videos that I can share. I am curious why you have some of the autoconfig being excluded as that stuff is what gives you access to JdbcTemplate

Comment: Spring Framework docs talk about the [IoC container](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html). Sections 7.1 and 7.2 have good overview information. 7.2.x sections start to get a little into the weeds so read if you want more context but don't try to understand it all right away. Drop down to the section on [Dependencies](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-dependencies) as that is the part that describes the `@Autowired`

Comment: As far as tutorial videos ... I have unfortunately ran into a lot of poorly created ones by searching for spring and dependency injection. The best of the bunch (20+ videos that I quickly skimmed) was [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQn9Z6bVggk)

Comment: Can you add your pom.xml ?

Comment: Sure @lazarov pox.xml added.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the JdbcTemplate bean in the xml config or java config however you are creating your beans xml might look like something like

```
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" 
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of xml file, I do prefer create that with config classes ex:

```
@Configuration
```

public class JpaConfig {

```
@Bean
public JdbcTemplate dataSource() {

   JdbcTemplate myJdbcTemplate = (your new custom instance)

    return myJdbcTemplate;
}
```

}

I've seem you're using Spring Boot, so be aware where you're gonna put the  "JpaConfig" class, it must be visible while the spring is scanning the classes to put inside its context.